# In Sharepoint, I want to trigger a workflow automatically every month which shows only the lists which has that particular months date

Tags: sharepoint, date, workflow

I am new to sharepoint... I have a question:

I have a list with many documents in it. I have a date column in that list.
For each month I would like to view only that particular month's list (i.e) select the list which has that month in the date field. I would like the list to get updated each month automatically according to the date specified in the date field. For now I am doing it manually by changing the today's date which I have set. I would like to make this an automatic process each month beginning.

Could anyone help me rearding this. I hope my question was clear...

Thanks..
sharmi.

Answer (score 0):

YOur questipn isn;t really clear to me, but I'll give it a go anyway. You could try to add calculated columns to the list, that display only the month part of the date in the desired column, by using the MONTH([Start Date]), where Start Date is the name of the column your date in it.

The part about the workflow is not clear at all, what do you want to do? IF all you want is to display that months items, then add the calculated column and the nfilter on it. Or, to go a step further, create 12 views on the list, one for each month, that filter based on the newly added calculated column.

Answer (score 0):

Also not clear to me, but here's some suggestions.

1> You can create a filtered view based on dates 
 - create view, filter where modified > [Today] - 30 for the past month.

2> You can create a workflow to do your updates. Use Information Management Policy Settings (in Library settings) and tell it to run your workflow every month and tell it to repeat.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You can use an information management policy.  On your list or library settings, click Information Management Policies.  Then click a content type and check the box next to "Retention".  That's where you add a stage.  As long as your workflow is set to allow it to be run manually, it will show in the list here, of stuff you can trigger. Thanks to Laura Rogers!